# Why does MPI_Send() with a non existent receiver give error instead of blocking forever?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I send a message from a process with rank 0 using the following command:

```
MPI_Send(sendmsg, strlen(sendmsg) + 1, MPI_CHAR, 1, 99, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

It is a message intended for process with rank 1.

Now, in my code, if the rank is 1, the program does not do anything. It simply calls MPI_Finalize() and returns. So, there is no MPI_Recv() call made if rank is 1.

I have read that MPI_Send is a blocking send and I think that means that the control does not return to the program until the contents of the buffer are received by some other process using MPI_Recv.

However, instead of the program getting stuck (waiting forever), which is what I expected, the program terminates with the following error message:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Send: Unknown error class, error stack:
PMPI_Send(159).............: MPI_Send(buf=0x7ffe29e24cc0, count=13, MPI_CHAR, dest=1, tag=99, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll(1845): Communication error with rank 1: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 2):

`MPI_Send()` is blocking in a sense it blocks until the send buffer can be reused.

That can happen even **before** the message is actually sent and/or a matching receive is posted.

If you want to block until a matching receive is posted, you can use `MPI_Ssend()` instead.

Comment: Could someone still explain why did this particular error show up? I am new to MPI. Also, how did the buffer become usable again?

Comment: @ShashankKumar calling `MPI_Finalize()` when there are pending messages is undefined behaviour. [The standard](https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) mandates (see p. 357) that each rank _"... must execute matching calls needed to complete MPI communications initiated by other processes."_ Failure to do so leads to undefined behaviour, including errors such as the one you are encountering. That error is due to how MPICH works internally and could be any other error as well.

Comment: @HristoIliev I see. An MPI_Finalize() call made by one MPI process is also communicated to other processes then?

Comment: @ShashankKumar not necessarily. What is happening in your case is that rank 1 closes the TCP socket(s) it uses for communication and rank 0 gets connection refused when it tries to progress the send operation.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.